# convert HTML symbol Code to actual symbol using Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

I am Building a quiz app for React.js practice and I'm having trouble with HTML Symbol codes in the API response. Codes like `&#039` are in the response instead of the actual apostrophe symbol. I understand the use of these codes, and why the JSON I am receiving from the API uses them I just cant find a way to make what is displayed be the symbol instead of the code. The same situation with `&` and quotation marks.

Is there a way to parse the string that I receive so that The questions and answers in my app look correctly when read?

I have tried using `DOMparser` to convert to html but that throws an error. And `String()` just gives me the same thing as the direct string from API.

example question:

API sends this:

`Which band had hits in 1975 with the songs, &#039;One Of These Nights&#039; &amp; &#039;Lyin Eyes&#039;?`

should look like this in App:

Which band had hits in 1975 with the songs, 'One Of These Nights' & 'Lyin Eyes'?

Comment: This is bad API design. The content in the response shouldn't be escaped in the first place. Do you have access to the backend?

Answer (score 0):

Try using HTML element as placeholder:

```
let container = document.createElement('div');
container.innerHTML = 'Which band had hits in 1975 with the songs, &#039;One Of These Nights&#039; &amp; &#039;Lyin Eyes&#039;?';

console.log(container.textContent);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` React prop, though like the name suggest it's dangerous. But if you're sure that this text will never insert any `<script>` tags, then you're fine

```js
function MyComponent() {
  const text = "Which band had hits in 1975 with the songs, &#039;One Of These Nights&#039; &amp; &#039;Lyin Eyes&#039;?";
  
  return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: text}} />;
}
```